# How hard is it to store user-inputted data?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-spinner, android-datepicker

I have a app and I recently added a DatePicker to my app but whenever a user enters a date and time and saves their project, when they return to work on it the work is gone as if it's never been started which leads me to assume it isn't being saved anywhere.

I'm just wondering how would I go abouts storing user inputted data to be persistent for my DatePicker/Spinner.

Below is my main_layout code for the date picker.

```
           <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/btn_timePicker"
                    android:text="What's the date?"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textTime"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    tools:text="@tools:sample/date/ddmmyy"/>





  btn_timePicker.setOnClickListener {
            saveData()
        }

     private fun saveData() {
        val insertedText = btn_timePicker.text.toString()
        textTime.text = insertedText

        val sharedPreferences  = getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
        editor.apply {
            putString("STRING_KEY", insertedText)
        }.apply()
        Toast.makeText(this@NewsActivity, "Data Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    private fun loadData() {
        val sharedPreferences  = getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val savedString = sharedPreferences.getString("STRING_KEY", null)

        textTime.text = savedString
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use roomDb for storing the complex data: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin#0
2. Or you can use dataStore for storing simple data: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-preferences-datastore#0

Answer (score 0):

It's not hard at all.
You can store user data in a couple of ways. One of them is using `SharedPrefrences` that you can learn about it [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm#:%7E:text=Shared%20Preferences%20allow%20you%20to,contains%20the%20values%20of%20preferences.).
The other way is to store it in a SQLite database that you can learn about [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite).
You can store it in a file on storage too but I don't recommend it at all.

Comment: Ah I just edited my post to include my attempt at the SharedPreference route, I tried but I was getting an error as shown in this screenshot https://gyazo.com/612286ea669de58a4fca62b5a0934b6d

It said none of the functions can be called with the argument supplied under the Toast.maketext so I don't know what the issue is currently

Comment: Not sure if anyone here would know the solution to the error I am getting but it's delaying me a good bit not knowing how to save the data inputted.

Comment: I think it's the context that I have as 'this' making the error.

Comment: yes it is the context, where are you using this method?

Comment: I fixed it with just doing this@NewsActivity but the thing is for my DatePicker, it still doesn't save the user-inputted date, i've updated this post with the updated code but yeah I don't know where I have went wrong but if you can see from above then that would be perfect.

Comment: It compiles without any errors, it's just that it doesn't save still which might mean a wrong inputted value somewhere.

Comment: use 'with (sharedPref.edit()) {
    putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score_key), newHighScore)
    apply()
}' instead of your code see if that works

Comment: and make sure the insertedText is not empty

Comment: `
 private fun saveData() {
        val insertedText = btn_timePicker.text.toString()
        textTime.text = insertedText
        val sharedPreferences  = getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
        with (sharedPreferences.edit()) { putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score_key), newHighScore)
        }.apply()
        Toast.makeText(this@NewsActivity, "Data Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    } `

Comment: Not sure how to print code in the replies that makes it look nice but not sure if i've put  that in the right place as it gives errors for 'newHighScore' and 'R.string.saved_high_score_key'  which gives the error unresolved reference

Comment: https://gyazo.com/2d2380762c3517793ca49d3183c95e1b 

That is where I think it goes but still errors under both for unresolved references.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231755/discussion-between-danial-iranpour-and-ronte).